# Reversing order of strings displayed

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently a beginner with `c#` `winforms` working on a little project.  I can't quite understand how to switch the order of my notes.

At the moment I have a notes class, and a `Addnote` button.  What the button does is take my input from one textbox, and displays it in the other.

Currently I have tried the `.Reverse()`

```
private void btnAddNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                 
    Notes note = new Notes(txtNoteWriter.Text);           
    txtNoteReader.Text += note.Note + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    txtNoteReader.Text.Reverse();
}
```

My class looks like this

```
class Notes
{
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public Notes(string note)
    {
        Note = note;           
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Note;
    }       
}
```

My button to add a note from `txtNoteWriter` to a read only `txtNoteReader` is

```
private void btnAddNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                 
    Notes note = new Notes(txtNoteWriter.Text);           
    txtNoteReader.Text += note.Note + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Currently I am trying to get it to save a note newest to oldest in terms of when they were submitted (currently it is in opposite order.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve this, following is one suggestion.

Since you need the timestamp along with the string that is added, you could make it part of the Notes Class. For example, modifying the notes class as follows.

```
class Notes
{
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public Notes(string note)
    {
        Note = note;
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Note}-{TimeStamp.ToString()}";

    }
}
```

Now, you can define a collection in your Main class which would hold every added Note.

```
private List<Notes> _notesCollection = new List<Notes>();
```

Finally, the btnAddNote click event would look like following

```
private List<Notes> _notesCollection = new List<Notes>();
private void btnAddNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var note = new Notes(txtNoteWriter.Text);
    _notesCollection.Add(note);
    txtNoteReader.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _notesCollection.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp).Select(x => x.ToString()));
}
```

In the button Click event, you are adding a new Note to the collection. Then, you are using LINQ to Order the collection based on the TimeStamp Property. For the purpose, you are using the [OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.8) method. The [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) method enables you to select what you need to display from the collection.

Finally, the [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) method allows you to join the different strings to form the final result.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I had a similar layout earlier but I couldn't get it to work.  I appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you @Adrian